# Subgroups of RAAGs vs. subgroups of RACGs

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

> Is a (finitely generated) torsion-free subgroup of a right-angled Coxeter group isomorphic to a subgroup of a right-angled Artin group?

It is well-known from the theory of special cube complexes that a subgroup $H$ of a right-angled Coxeter group $G$ contains a finite-index subgroup isomorphic to a subgroup of a right-angled Artin group (e.g. $H \cap [G,G]$), but is it true for the whole group if we assume in addition that $H$ is torsion-free?

The difficulty when applying the theory of special cube complexes comes from the fact that the induced action of $H$ on the usual CAT(0) cube complex $X$ of $G$ may invert hyperplanes (i.e. some isometries may stabilise a hyperplane and switch its halfspaces). This can be avoided by replacing $X$ with its barycentric subdivision, but then hyperplane-inversions yield self-osculations (i.e. there exist an element $h \in H$ and an oriented hyperplane $\vec{J}$ such that $\vec{J}$ and $g \vec{J}$ contain two intersecting oriented edges pointing to their common vertex and that do not span a square).

**NB:** In all the question, right-angled Artin/Coxeter groups are finitely generated. Recall that, given a (finite) simplicial graph $\Gamma$, the associated right-angled Coxeter group is defined by the presentation
$$\langle u \in V(\Gamma) \mid u^2=1 \ (u \in V(\Gamma)), \ [u,v]=1 \ (\{u,v\} \in E(\Gamma)) \rangle$$
and the associated right-angled Artin group by the presentation
$$\langle u \in V(\Gamma) \mid [u,v]=1 \ (\{u,v\} \in E(\Gamma)) \rangle$$
where $V(\Gamma)$ and $E(\Gamma)$ denote respectively the vertex- and edge-sets of $\Gamma$.

Comment: RAACGs are not virtually torsion-free? Did you see this: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82768543.pdf

Comment: f.g. RAACG are virtually torsion-free. But not orbitrary RAACG, since these include the group of finitely supported permutations of the integers.

Comment: I guess the braid group $B_4$ is not isomorphic to any subgroup of any Coxeter group. (If it were, we would deduce its linearity, which was hard to establish. Anyway that's not a proof).

Comment: @MarkSapir: Sure, but that only proves that torsion-free subgroups of RACGs are **virtually** subgroups of RAAGs. My question asks precisely whether or not the *virtually* can be removed.

Comment: @YCor: I don't see the connection between your comment and my question. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think @YCor's point was that $B_4$ can't embed in a RAAG, so one could wonder whether it embeds in a RACG and hence serves as a counterexample, but "probably" $B_4$ also can't embed in a RACG. (Actually all of this could be said already for $B_3$.) (For the record I can't think of any other candidate counterexamples.)

Comment: @MattZaremsky: I see. Is it easy to prove that $B_4$ does not embed in a RAAG?

Comment: Sorry for adding mess, indeed my comment was irrelevant since $B_4$ is not a RAAG.

Comment: @AGenevois: The proof I know that $B_4$ (even $B_3$) doesn't embed into any RAAG (as told to me by Thomas Koberda) is that thanks to residual torsion-free nilpotence, any non-abelian subgroup of a RAAG must surject onto $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and of course braid groups can't do this.

Comment: @MattZaremsky: Aren't RACG residually nilpotent? Also see https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00013-019-01332-7.pdf, Theorem 1 (ii).

Comment: @MarkSapir: That sounds right, so I think my one trick for seeing something doesn't embed in a RAAG also makes it not embed in a RACG, and hence is not much help for this question.

Comment: @MattZaremsky: Thank you. In fact, RAAGs satisfy a strong Tits alternative: every finitely generated subgroup either is abelian or it surjects onto $\mathbb{F}_2$. For RACGs, you have something similar, every finitely generated subgroup either is virtually abelian or it surjects onto a non-elementary free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So you get a similar obstruction: for finitely generated subgroups, the abelianisation cannot be cyclic.

Comment: @MarkSapir isn't the (sub)question rather whether torsion-free f.g. subgroups of RACG residually (torsion-free nilpotent)?

Comment: @YCor, Anthony’s answer also answers this subquestion, since all its noncyclic quotients are dihedral. I suspect the fundamental group of the surface of Euler characteristic -1 also fails to be residually torsion-free nilpotent, but don’t know a proof.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fundamental group of the (non-orientable) closed surface of Euler characteristic -1 provides a counterexample.

On the one hand, it’s a subgroup of index 4 in the reflection group on the right-angled pentagon, so it embeds in a RACG, and of course it’s torsion-free.

On the other hand, [Crisp—Wiest](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0303217v2) proved that it never embeds in a RAAG.

Comment: Just for the reader: it has presentation $\langle x,y,z\mid x^2y^2z^2\rangle$.

Comment: That it doesn't embed into a RAAG directly follows from the fact mentioned by Anthony that a nonabelian f.g. subgroup of a RAAG surjects onto $F_2$. Indeed the $\chi=-1$ surface group doesn't surject onto $F_2$, since any three elements $x,y,z$ in a free group satisfying $x^2y^2z^2=1$ commute (Lyndon, 1959).

Comment: @YCor: That's a nice modern way of thinking about it (as long as the reader is happy with Lyndon's theorem). The strong Tits alternative for subgroups of RAAGs wasn't in the literature at the time of Crisp--Wiest's paper. Their strategy is to generalise the proof of Lyndon's theorem from free groups to RAAGs.

Comment: Nice example, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a elementary example:
$$BS(1,-1):= \langle x,y \mid yxy^{-1}=x^{-1} \rangle.$$
It embeds into $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{D}_\infty$, which itself embeds in the right-angled Coxeter group $\mathbb{D}_\infty \oplus \mathbb{D}_\infty$. Indeed, if $\mathbb{Z} = \langle t \mid \ \rangle$ and $\mathbb{D}_\infty = \langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2=1 \rangle$, then $\langle ab,ta \rangle$ is isomorphic to $BS(1,-1)$.

But $BS(1,-1)$ does not embed into a right-angled Artin group. To see this, one can use a theorem due to Baudisch that claims that a $2$-generated subgroup in a right-angled Artin group is abelian or free. One can also use the fact that right-angled Artin groups are bi-orderable, which is not the case for $BS(1,-1)$: if $x>1$, then $x^{-1}=yxy^{-1}>yy^{-1}=1$ hence $x<1$.

Comment: Or you can just use the “strong Tits alternative” you quoted above, since this group is non-abelian but doesn’t surject a free group. Perhaps it’s worth pointing out that  $BS(1,-1)$ is the Klein bottle group, so this example is quite similar to the one I gave, being the next simplest non-orientable surface group. Actually, Lyndon’s theorem is easy to prove, so the two examples are almost equally “elementary”.

Comment: That's the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. So at this point the list consists of the first two infinite fundamental groups of non-orientable surfaces?

Comment: @StefanWitzel: Right. At first, I did not realise that I was looking at the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. I was looking at virtually abelian subgroups : in RACGs, virtually abelian subgroups correspond to subgroups in $\mathbb{D}_\infty^n$ for some $n \geq 1$, and I realised that it was possible to find torsion-free subgroups that are not abelian. Maybe there are other interesting phenomena there. (But I am not sure. I do not have a proof, but it's not impossible that all torsion-free non-abelian subgroups contain $BS(1,-1)$.)

Comment: @AGenevois: I see, for virtually abelian this looks optimal. I was rather wondering whether there is a common theme: if $\pi$ is the fundamental group of a non-orientable surface then the index-$2$ subgroup corresponding to the orientable cover embeds into a RAAG but for $\pi$ itself this is obstructed by the orientation representation $H^2(\pi;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ somehow. But that's just a naive extrapolation, I haven't thought in that direction, just "wondered".

Comment: @StefanWitzel: I wondered the same question, but Crisp and Wiest proved that the only surface groups that do not embed in RAAGs are the fundamental groups of the projective plane, the Klein bottle, and the surface of Euler characteristic $-1$. All the others are subgroups of RAAGs.

Comment: In fact, it's a common theme that these two surface groups have unusually poor residual properties. Indeed, they are the only two torsion-free surface groups that aren't limit groups.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I would like to add a few details and references regarding Henry's answer.

First, the right-angled Coxeter group $C$ defined by a cycle of length five can be realised as the reflection group generated by the reflections along the sides of a right-angled pentagon in the hyperbolic plane. As described in Scott's article *Subgroups of surface groups are almost geometric*, if $x_1,\ldots, x_5$ denote the five reflections generating our Coxeter group (see the figure below), then $x_1x_2x_5$, $x_1x_4$, $x_3x_5$, and $x_1x_3x_1x_5$ generate a subgroup with a fundamental domain that is a union of four pentagons.
[image]

By looking at how the sides of this fundamental domain are identified, we deduce that the subgroup $G$ under consideration is the fundamental group of a non-orientable surface of Euler characteristic $-1$.

Now, the fact that $G$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of a right-angled Artin group is proved, as mentioned by Henry, by Crisp and Wiest in their article *Embeddings of graph braid and surface groups in right-angled Artin groups and braid groups*. It is also a consequence of a strong Tits alternative satisfied by right-angled Artin groups: every subgroup is abelian or it surjects onto a non-abelian free group. An algebraic proof can be found in Antolin and Minasyan's article *Tits alternative for graph products*; and a topological argument can be found in Bregman's article *Automorphisms and homology of non-positively curved cube complexes*.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the picture I had in mind!